# Best way to filter and find unique values two times in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to find a way to find the unique values of column 1 and find the unique items in column 2 that corresponds to each item in column 1 so I can map the "higher level" stuff the "lower level" stuff.

For example, the excel sheet would look like this

```
Column 1         Column 2          Column 3 
New York         Brooklyn          ....more information about col 2 
New York         Manhattan 
New York         Staten Island 
New York         Queens 
New York         Bronx 
New Jersey       Newark 
New Jersey       Jersey City 
New Jersey       Edison 
CT               Hartford 
CT               Windsor
```

I would have to gather Brooklyn, Manhttan, Staten Island, Queens and Bronx when New York is chosen. (I am making a listbox so that when New York is selected, the above boroughs show up on the second listbox but I can't figure out how to grab the borough information when the user specifies the State is NY. I need a way for excel to search through the excel sheet until it finds New York and then looks at the cells next to column with New York)

What is the best way to do this and how will I actually do it?  Dictionary, collections, for loop, autofilter?

Comment: I think you are trying to make [Dynamic Dependant List?](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if You have a lot of data it might be faster to use dictionary. However in dictionary You must have unique ID for each record + You will have to somehow process the data.

But You can also use For Each loop.
I assume that You will go through all cells, e. g. in column A. You are looking for a specific record, e. g. "New York" if You find it, then You save row number to long variable "start" and then proceed with your loop untill the cell value <> "New York". If You reach this point, the value of "end row" should be loop step - 1. Then You can proceed with the next loop that will add elements to the list box from column B (or next column).

Sollution that I've saw in "commercial" spreadsheet was that in a user form You had text box (input) and a list box. When You type something into input (text box) then after each letter macro fires and it makes autofilter in hidden (vba hidden) tab. Then it proceeds a for each loop in this tab in range set by xlCellTypeVisible and adding data to list box.

All in all it depends on amount of data and You will have to try Yourself which sollution suits You best.